# Lomb-Scargle and evenly spaced data

Tags: statistical-significance, signal-processing, numerics

Currently I am implementing computer program for calculating periodograms using Lomb-Scargle method. I have implemented two methods, one using double precision arithmetics (~16 significant decimal places) and another using single precision arithmetics (~8 significant decimal places). To verify that my computations are correct I implemented automatised test that compares results gained by these two methods. Most of the time the relative differences are < 1e-5 which is good. You must understand that Lomb-Scargle method is iterative. The length of calculation is dependend on the length of input data. So the calculation error grows from about 1e-8 to 1e-5 during calculation. This is understandable. These are the formulas used:

[image]

[image]

There is not any problem using data sets from real life. But this methods has problems with some synthetic data sets. Let me explain this:

1. If you analyze the first formula you can see that it contains division operator. For some special cases the values in denominators can be zero. I noticed this using my automatized tests. For these cases there were large relative differences between results gained by double and single precision arithmetics. This occurs using evenly sampled data and frequency w being either Nyquist frequency or integer multiple of it. This is OK and I have no problem with it. I can be sure that for real problem being solved in praxis this will never occur. It has simple explanation if you think a little about it. Lomb-Scargle method is approximation method trying to find the best fit by applying least-square rule. If you take one or two samples per period you cannot in general say, what is the amplitude or phase of the signal (forgot about diode and capacitor being used in praxis for finding signal peak).
2. Another case is when formula for computing tan(2wtau) diverges. It again occurs for evenly sampled data and using frequency "w" which is one sixth of sampling frequency. For this case assuming that length of input data is divisible by six the value in denominator is zero:

T = 6 * Ts or w = ws / 6

[image]

What is interpretation of this ? How can I be sure that it never happens for real data ?

Sources:

1. William H. Press, Saul A. Teukolsky, William T. Vetterling: Numerical recipes in C, p. 577 (can be downloaded from here http://freecomputerbooks.com/Numerical-Recipes-in-C-Second-Edition.html)